# Generate bearer tokens for social logged in users spring boot

Tags: spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2, idp

I have a authorization server which generates and store bearer tokens for username and password log in using the oauth2 password grant. I want to integrate social sign in (Google and facebook) to my existing authorization server. Since my other resources are protected by authorization server how do I generate a Bearer tokens for google/facebook signed in users ? so i can access my protected resources using that token.

Note: Bearer tokens are stored in mysql db. (Using JdbcTokenStore)

Since I already have password grant implementation, I'am glad if you can give me direction to do with the current authorization service using spring-boot and spring security.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main ways to implement this:

- Federation, so that the Authorization Server manages integration with social identity providers
- Handle different providers in your apps, which will add complexity to both your UIs and APIs

Personally I much prefer the first option, which only requires configuration changes - and no code changes in UIs and APIs. My [Federated Logins Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) may help you to understand your architectural choices.

It is worth doing some early technical testing to see if these steps work:

- Adding an OAuth web client to Google / Facebook
- Adding an Identity Provider to your Authorization Server

Comment: if you know implementation approach to the second way, please share with me.